# Count instances of ALL words in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I have an excel sheet with a bunch of text strings of varying length.

What I need to be able to do is found the instances of each different word on sheet2 of the doc.
I could use countif but I'd have to right a different one for each different word (50-70 different words). Or the substitute/LEN functions since they are different texts things. I really don't fancy doing that for each word.

Is there a way of getting excel to print the word and count of the word instances for every single word in a document ideally to the second sheet of the document?

Comment: Is this a one time operation or do you want it to update live as you add more strings to the sheet?

Comment: Please edit your post to show a screenshot of the data you want to count, a mockup of your expected outcome and some details of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I located a nice
[VBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications)
macro in the post
[Is there a way (formulaic or vba solution) to create a listing of all words in a column and the number](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/is-there-a-way-formulaic-or-vba-solution-to-create-a-listing-of-all-words-in-a-column-and-the-number.693944/).

The last entry in the post contains a VBA function that creates
a new sheet named "Unique Words" and returns in it all the unique words
with a count of their number of occurrences.
It assumes the data in in column A of the active sheet, so will need
to be modified for your case.
I have tested it and it works correctly.

To use VBA in a spreadsheet, it must be saved as `.xlsm` (not as `.xlsx`).
You must also
[Show the Developer tab](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/show-the-developer-tab-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45).

Do this when all is ready:

- To open the VBA editor press
  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>
- In the Insert menu select Module; the editor should open
- Copy & Paste the below code
- Press
  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>
  to return to Excel
- In the Developer pane, click Macros, select the new macro, finally
  click Run.

This is the function code:

```
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Module    : CountUniqueWordsInRange
' Author    : JoeMo
' Date      : 3/28/2013
' Purpose   : Run from the activesheet. Assumes all data are in column A of the activesheet.
'             Requires that words are separated by the space character.
'             Returns all unique words with a count of the number of occurrences of
'             each word in column A to a new sheet named "Unique Words".
'             Limit on total word count that can be handled
'             is 17,179,869,184 (Excel 2007 or later versions). Limit on number of
'             unique words that can be handled is 1,048,575 (Excel 2007 or later versions).
'             Treats numbers and acronyms as words.
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Sub CountUniqueWordsInRange()
Dim rS As Range, sSht As Worksheet, dSht As Worksheet, aSht As Worksheet
Dim Punc As Variant, lRs As Long, lRd As Long, c As Range
Dim totWords As Long, colCt As Long, vA As Variant, vO() As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, Ct As Long, n As Long
'define source range
Set sSht = ActiveSheet
lRs = sSht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rS = sSht.Range("A1", "A" & lRs)
'Get total word count
totWords = CountWords(rS)
'determine how many columns needed to list all words
colCt = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(totWords / Rows.Count, 0)
If colCt > Columns.Count Then
    MsgBox "Too many words to list in one sheet - truncate the input range and try again." & vbNewLine & "Goodbye."
    Exit Sub
End If
With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
.DisplayAlerts = False
.StatusBar = "PROCESSING YOUR DATA - PLEASE BE PATIENT"
End With
'Add sheet to list all words in source range
On Error Resume Next
Worksheets("All Words").Delete
On Error GoTo 0
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add after:=sSht
Set aSht = ActiveSheet
aSht.Name = "All Words"
'list all words
Punc = Array(".", ",", ";", ":", "?", "!", "~", "@", "#", "$", _
    "(", ")", "/", Chr(34), Chr(147), Chr(148))
For Each c In rS
    If Not IsEmpty(c) Then
        vA = Split(Trim(c.Value), " ")
        Ct = Ct + UBound(vA) + 1
        ReDim Preserve vO(1 To Ct)
        For i = LBound(vA) To UBound(vA)
            For j = LBound(Punc) To UBound(Punc)
                vA(i) = Replace(vA(i), Punc(j), "")
            Next j
        Next i
        For j = LBound(vA) To UBound(vA)
            k = k + 1
            vO(k) = vA(j)
        Next j
    End If
Next c
'put all words into All Words sheet
k = 0
n = 0
For i = 1 To colCt
    Do Until n = aSht.Rows.Count Or k = UBound(vO)
        k = k + 1
        n = n + 1
        aSht.Cells(n, i).Value = vO(k)
    Loop
    n = 0
Next i
'copy all words to sheet "Unique Words" and remove duplicates
On Error Resume Next
Worksheets("Unique Words").Delete
On Error GoTo 0
aSht.Copy after:=sSht
Set dSht = ActiveSheet
dSht.Name = "Unique Words"
For i = 1 To colCt
    dSht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(i).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
Next i
'Get word count remaining after dups removal from individual columns
totWords = CountWords(dSht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion)
If totWords > dSht.Rows.Count Then
    MsgBox "Too many words remaining for a single column after first pass - Goodbye."
    Exit Sub
End If
'Consolidate columns and remove dups again
With dSht
    lRd = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    For i = 2 To colCt
        .Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp)).Cut Destination:=Cells(lRd, 1)
    Next i
End With
'Final dups removal from the one remaining column
dSht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
dSht.Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert
With dSht.Range("A1:B1")
    .Value = Array("Word", "Count")
    .Font.Bold = True
End With
'Get count of each unique word
lRd = dSht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
dSht.Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF('All Words'!C[-1]:C[" & colCt - 2 & "],'Unique Words'!RC[-1])"
With dSht.Range("B2", "B" & lRd)
    .FillDown
    .Calculate
    .Copy
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With
With dSht.Range("A1:B1")
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With
With Application
.ScreenUpdating = True
.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
.DisplayAlerts = True
.StatusBar = False
End With
End Sub
Function CountWords(R As Range) As Long
Dim lChars As Long, c As Range, Ct As Long
For Each c In R
    Ct = 0
    lChars = Len(Trim(c.Value))
    If lChars = 0 Then
        Ct = 0
    Else
        Ct = Len(Trim(c.Value)) - Len(Replace(Trim(c.Value), " ", "")) + 1
    End If
    CountWords = CountWords + Ct
Next c
End Function
```

Some helpful references:

- [Quick start: Create a macro](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/quick-start-create-a-macro-741130ca-080d-49f5-9471-1e5fb3d581a8)
- [How to Run a Macro in Excel – A Complete Step-by-Step Guide](https://trumpexcel.com/run-a-macro-excel/)

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of Excel, this can be done with three formulas on a second sheet.

---

**First Formula**

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,Sheet1!1:1048576)," ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>", "//s")
```

Replace `Sheet1` with whatever your sheet name actually is. You may need to wrap it in single quotes if it has spaces like `'First Sheet'`.

- `TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,Sheet1!1:1048576)` combines all the cells in the entire sheet into one giant string. If this is not what you want, you can limit the range into whatever cells you actually care about. The text is separated by `</s><s>` which will make more sense in a minute. ([Reference](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c))
- `SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(~)," ","</s><s>")` will replace any spaces in your text with the same `</s><s>` that we used before. Now you have a list of every word from every cell in the entire sheet. If you also have words separated by commas, semicolons, or periods, you can add additional `SUBSTITUTE()` functions to replace all those. ([Reference](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/substitute-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332))
- `FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(~) & "</s></t>", "//s")` is where the real magic happens. The function is not explicitly meant for this purpose but you can use it to turn a delimited string into an array instead. This lets us split up the string into individual cells. All the XML tags like `<t>` and `<s>` are to make the string look like XML. This is why we used `</s><s>` earlier. ([Reference](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filterxml-function-4df72efc-11ec-4951-86f5-c1374812f5b7))

---

**Second Formula**

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(A2#))
```

Replace `A2` with wherever the first formula is.

- `UNIQUE(~)` will filter out the duplicate items from the list. ([Reference](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unique-function-c5ab87fd-30a3-4ce9-9d1a-40204fb85e1e))
- `Sort(Unique(~))` will sort that list of unique words. This isn't necessary but it is nice. ([Reference](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sort-function-22f63bd0-ccc8-492f-953d-c20e8e44b86c))
- The other fancy bit here is `A2#` (where `A2` is where the first formula is). The `#` at the end tells Excel to spill the formula down to the end of the list that starts at `A2`. As you add / remove words from `Sheet1`, the size of the list returned by the first formula will change. Having this dynamic reference in the second formula means it will *also* change size to match. You can tell when a formula is spilling because the range will have a blue border when you select some cell within it.

---

**Third Formula**

```
=COUNTIF(A2#,B2#)
```

Replace `A2` with wherever the first formula is and `B2` with wherever the second formula is.

This formula is *much* simpler. All it does is search the total word list for each of the unique words. Again, the `#` tells it to consider the entire list starting at the first cell of each.

---

**Results**

You can turn this:

[image: Before]

Into this:

[image: After]